# How can I extract the perfmon counter "Memory: Pages/Sec" using t-sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, monitoring, perfmon

I've googled this and so far, no luck so turning to all you awesome gurus for help.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to get the perfmon counter "Memory: Pages/Sec" using t-sql as I'm trying to add it as a custom metric in our Ignite monitoring tool.  I've looked at the sys.dm_os_performance_counters DMV but didn't find it there.

Anyone know of a way doing this?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Pages of what per second? SQL Server exposes evictions this way, as well as readahead, checkpoint, background writer, pages allocated, and pages compressed. But not just a generic pages/sec, what would this actually mean within SQL Server and how would you troubleshoot it?

Comment: THere is a generic script on [database journal](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3914366/Collecting-Performance-Metrics-Using-SQL-Server-DMV.htm) that will serve as a good starting point.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I'm looking for the "Memory: Pages/Sec" perfmon counter that indicates there is hard page faulting.

Comment: sys.dm_os_performance_counters only exposes to SQL Server the metrics that are relevant to that instance. You'll need to get generic operating-system level metrics elsewhere.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: so would it even be possible to get OS-level metrics via t-sql?  Or would I need to use powershell to tap into WMI?

Comment: Does Ignite only support getting anything from T-SQL or Powershell? I'd be surprised if there isn't a way to hook into perfmon directly, which will be more efficient than WMI I suspect.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Not sure what Ignite supports or its limitations are. I mean it "should" be able to get metrics via Powershell.

Comment: @Kin: thanks for the link, more reading for me, yay!

Comment: Honestly, you should contact SolarWinds and ask them the best way to add Memory: Pages/Sec as a custom metric. That's exactly what their support department is there for. Jumping to the conclusion that Powershell must be the best way might be a good guess, but I'd rather get an authoritative answer. YMMV.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thank you! I'll try that route...

Answer (score 2):

Following @Srutzky's example of just looking at page faults/sec (not pages/sec), you can do this:

```
DECLARE @before BIGINT, @after BIGINT;

SELECT @before = page_fault_count FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';

SELECT @after = page_fault_count FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;

SELECT PageFaultsPerSec = (1.0*@after - @before)/10.0;
```

It is likely that you can just have Ignite poll for the following metric:

```
SELECT page_fault_count FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory
```

And then set up alerts based on thresholds or deltas. But I still recommend you contact them to find out how to best implement a custom metric based on a column from an arbitrary DMV, which might be different from the perf counters DMV.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally / in the long-term, I do agree with @Aaron ([comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127625/how-can-i-extract-the-perfmon-counter-memory-pages-sec-using-t-sql/127636#comment236478_127625) on the Question) about contacting SolarWinds to request that they create a custom metric for this. But even if you do that *and* they accept the idea, it could take a while for them to release it. In the mean time, or if you ever just want to view this info in an ad hoc fashion, you can try the following:

***IF*** that metric really is the same as the "Page Faults" metric as reported by `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS` <sup>(Please see **Notes** at the bottom)</sup>, then you can do something like the following:

```sql
DECLARE @BeginningValue TABLE
(
  [Counter] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  [Value] BIGINT NOT NULL,
  [InsertTime] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE())
);
DECLARE @EndingValue TABLE
(
  [Counter] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  [Value] BIGINT NOT NULL,
  [InsertTime] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE())
);
---

INSERT INTO @BeginningValue ([Counter], [Value])
  EXEC ('DBCC MEMORYSTATUS;');

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.000'; -- 10 second pause

INSERT INTO @EndingValue ([Counter], [Value])
  EXEC ('DBCC MEMORYSTATUS;');
---

DELETE FROM @BeginningValue WHERE [Counter] <> N'Page Faults';
DELETE FROM @EndingValue WHERE [Counter] <> N'Page Faults';

SELECT lst.Value AS [EndingValue], frst.Value AS [BeginningValue],
       lst.InsertTime AS [EndingTime], frst.InsertTime AS [BeginningTime],
       (lst.Value - frst.Value) AS [Difference],
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, frst.InsertTime, lst.InsertTime) AS [NumSeconds],
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(14, 4),
               (((lst.Value - frst.Value) * 1.0) /
                        DATEDIFF(SECOND, frst.InsertTime, lst.InsertTime))
              ) AS [PageFaults/Sec]
FROM   @BeginningValue frst
CROSS JOIN @EndingValue lst;
```

Returns:

```
Ending  Beginning  EndingTime               BeginningTime            Diff  Sec.  Faults/Sec
418529  418497     2016-01-28 13:13:27.850  2016-01-28 13:13:17.827  32    10    3.2000
```

**Notes**

- If you are on SQL Server 2008 or newer, then please use the [sys.dm_os_process_memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510747.aspx) DMV (as pointed out in @Aaron's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127660/30859)), else you can use `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS` as I have shown above. I had only recommended `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS` (and hence this method of capturing the info it returns) due to overlooking that field being returned from any DMV. But I have tested them both and they return the same value, so there is really no good reason to use `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS` given the extra work entailed if you have access to the `sys.dm_os_process_memory` DMV.
- I had not elaborated on this in my initial posting of this answer, but 10 seconds between samples is actually rather low and will likely decrease the accuracy of the resulting metric. Ideally a larger number -- at least 30, if not 60, seconds -- would be used. However, the concern is that having a monitoring tool call this code (I assumed it would be placed into a Stored Procedure) introduces a potential risk in the monitoring software considering the delay to be a timeout, or somehow delays its processing or collection of other metrics. Hence, I used 10 seconds as a means of favoring reliability over accuracy. This goes back to what I said at the very beginning about agreeing with @Aaron's position of the ideal scenario being that the software vendor provides a native / built-in means of collecting this information.

Comment: Well that's a lot of work compared to `SELECT page_fault_count FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;`. :-) I think the issue is still whether Ignite supports a SQL statement (or a batch like the one you show) as a custom metric. It might be very easy to plug it in, but it might not. What it more likely is that it can monitor the output of a simple query, and keep track of deltas between each poll. Not many monitoring tools will encourage you to put arbitrary waitfors etc. into their code path.

Comment: @AaronBertrand True. I looked through some DMVs earlier and didn't see it which is why I went with the `DBCC`. The silver-lining for that effort (if any) is that `dm_os_process_memory` does not seem to be available in SQL Server 2005, so this still could prove helpful to some ;-) I will make a note about these in my answer after dinner.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Answer has been updated.